# How to get a Hyper-V VM out of PausedCritical state?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v

A program running in a VM filled so much of the virtual disk that it expanded to fill the host's drive.  Now GET-VM shows the VM is in PausedCritical state.  I read that I need to compact the virtual disk, and that the VM must be in Off state first, but STOP-VM failed.  How can I stop the VM, so I can compact its virtual disk?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to free up space on the host drive or expand that drive. Specifically you need to free up 200mb at least.    Are there other vms that you can move off temporarily?  Can you shrink any of the other disks on other vms?

Comment: Also are there any snap shots that can be deleted?